# Change the name of a desktop environment on the GDM and Unity Greeter login screens

Tags: gnome, compiz, desktop-environments, gdm, unity-greeter

I want to know how to rename a desktop environment in Ubuntu to a custom name --

What I want to do is change the `Gnome Flashback (Compiz)` desktop to one called `nekOS 7 Public Beta`

as well as the `Gnome Flashback (Metacity)` one to `nekOS 7 Public Beta (LGM)` for "Low Graphics Mode," since Metacity is "lighter on the system."

Any way to accomplish this?

An image of what I am talking about: [image: Ubuntu desktop selector]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for LightDM, GDM, KDM and LXDM:

Desktop environment choices in e.g. unity greeter are defined by `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/xsessions` (X.org) and `/usr/share/wayland-sessions` (Wayland). These should be added automatically when you install a desktop environment from the official ubuntu repositories. Edit the corresponding file (e.g. `openbox.desktop` if you want to rename openbox) and change the name (the line starting with `Name=...`).