# How to remove Unity from the available desktop managers in 18.04

Tags: apt, unity, gnome

When I log into Ubuntu I have two options in the gear window:

- Gnome on Xorg
- Ubuntu

It looks like the "Ubuntu" option is the "Unity Desktop Environment"

How can I uninstall it and remove this option from my drop down?

I followed the directions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/651088/420898) but it is still listed as an option in the drop down.

In my terminal `sudo apt-get remove unity` returns `Package 'unity' is not installed, so not removed`

and `sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop` returns `Package 'ubuntu-desktop' is not installed, so not removed`

However, Unity is still an option at login and it still loads the Unity desktop.

Very frustrating!

Comment: Did you upgrade your system from an older release?  Ubuntu means the default DEsktop, which for 18.04 is GNOME with some 'flavoring' (tweaks etc).  Unity was the last Ubuntu-Desktop for 17.04 and before, being replaced by GNOME for 17.10 & 18.04

Comment: @guiverc Yes, I upgraded from 17.10.  However, now I want Unity off of my computer.  Logging into "Ubuntu" now loads the Unity Desktop (I think - or at least something that looks identical to Unity)

Comment: If you installed 17.10 and upgraded from there, you are using GNOME only; you're talking about the Ubuntu flavor of GNOME.  If you `dpkg -l *unity*` you'll see a list of packages which include the name unity in them, I suspect most unity packages will have 'un'  (uninstalled) and not 'ii" (installed), though my box has a few GtkMenuShell things that are common in gnome & unity).  I suspect you want vanilla GNOME & not Ubuntu GNOME.  Have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/964598/how-do-i-get-a-vanilla-gnome-after-ubuntu-17-04

Comment: The only things showing as `ii` with `dpkg -l *unity*` are 3 things that look like: `ii  libunity-protocol-private0`.  The link you shared does not tell me how to get rid of the Ubuntu option in the greeter. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: No I don't, as the only things I can think of would impact GNOME. If you had other non-gnome options it would be a Yes (but would remove both your current gnome options)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1022047/354663), for many display managers (including GDM) the desktop environment choices are stored as `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/xsessions` (X.org) and `/usr/share/wayland-sessions` (Wayland). Remove the corresponding `.desktop` file and the desktop environment won't show up in the greeter.

Comment: But does this actually delete the desktop environment? I want to make sure the package is removed, not just hidden.

Comment: @Startec the prompts you showed in the question state that `unity` is not installed already

Comment: @Startec No, but your question was "How to remove Unity from the available desktop managers".  You can have a look at the `.desktop` files which desktop environment they actually execute. As guiverc said in the comments, 17.10 shipped with gnome by default. If you didn't install unity yourself, it is probably not installed.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin so what is the other "Ubuntu" desktop environment option?  I have two desktop environments installed - I just one one of them installed.

Comment: @Startec when uninstalling software some configuration files may be left behind.. This is one of such cases. Did you even try to load the other desktop environment?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin yes and it loaded what looked like Unity. The dock was on the left and everything else looked like it too.

Comment: @Startec are you sure it's unity? It should be gnome with extensions that make it look like the old unity. The packet manager says you don't have unity installed, so it can't be it.

Comment: I see. Then, you are all right, I guess just deleting the `.desktop` file is enough. Thanks